# Why isn't it working when i read my data of a file but it works when they're hard coded?

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I had my data hardcoded like so:

```
labels1 = [{'yMax': u'780.797833935018', 'xMax': u'587.5438596491229', 'xMin': u'366.84210526315786',
                'yMin': u'613.9097472924188', 'id': '1', 'name': ''},
               {'yMax': u'244.37184115523468', 'xMax': u'2096.6666666666665', 'xMin': u'2057.8947368421054',
                'yMin': u'125.16606498194946', 'id': '2', 'name': ''}]
```

and it worked as expected in later steps.

However my data is thousands of lines so i have to format it , print it on a txt file then read it of it the method is used to write it :

```
f.write('{{\'yMax\': u\'{}\', \'xMax\': u\'{}\', \'xMin\': u\'{}\',\'yMin\': u\'{}\', \'id\': \'{}\', \'name\': \'\'}}\n'.format(ymax, xmax, xmin, ymin,id))
```

Then the method i used to read it off that file :

```
with open('1-0.txt') as f:
    labels1 = f.readlines()
labels1 = [x.strip() for x in labels1]
print(labels1)
```

the output of the print was :

```
["{'yMax': u'156', 'xMax': u'4802', 'xMin': u'4770','yMin': u'141', 'id': '1', 'name': ''}","{'yMax': u'156', 'xMax': u'4956', 'xMin': u'4931','yMin': u'145', 'id': '4', 'name': ''}"]
```

(not same exact data for the 2 but shouldn't matter), however with these values , when i read them using the code described above they just don't work in later steps as expected, why?!

Comment: @pilu gives you the right answer, don't try to do something already done by powerful libs :)

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially reading and writing dictionaries, which are handled very well using the `json` module.

Try something like this (where I renamed `labels1` to `data` just because):

```
import json    

# Write the data to a file.
with open('1-0.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(data))

# Read them back.
with open('1-0.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

Comment: I adjusted the following ` f.write(json.dumps('{{\'yMax\': u\'{}\', \'xMax\': u\'{}\', \'xMin\': u\'{}\',\'yMin\': u\'{}\', \'id\': \'{}\', \'name\': \'\'}}'.format(ymax, xmax, xmin, ymin,id)))` then used the read method described in the answer but i got this error ` raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 91 - line 1 column 152157 (char 90 - 152156)
`

Comment: replace `{` by `[` in the beggining of your hardcoded dataset: its an array of dictionaries. Same for the last `}`, make it `]`. This is how it is in your original question as well.

If you want something else answered please provide it in your question where I can read it with some indentation please.

Comment: My issue isn't with the hardcoded version, it works just fine with `[ ]`, in fact i got an error when i switched to `{ }` just now to test.

Comment: Yea, `{ }` initialize a dictionary which is a key -> value mapping. You need an array to store multiple such dictionaries. Can you show how the text file you are trying to read look like? Because I now understand that you not the one writing it, right?

Comment: Well basically the hardcoded version worked and it was a list of dictionaries,as shared above in my question, now regarding the txt version i shared how i treated them and it didn't work, then i followed the method you described and it didn't work also.

Comment: The only reason I see why it wouldn't work is that your text file does not contain what we think it contains (a list of dicts). Can you show a part of it? Only this was can we torubleshoot it.

Comment: `{'yMax': u'156', 'xMax': u'4802', 'xMin': u'4770','yMin': u'141', 'id': '1', 'name': ''}
{'yMax': u'157', 'xMax': u'4895', 'xMin': u'4810','yMin': u'141', 'id': '2', 'name': ''}` they look like this but each on a line, that being said i took the hardcoded version an put it in a file and it also failed to read it, that makes me think i'm failing to read it properly.

Comment: Oh i think i can think of a possible reason, it's reading every line as a string {} included, it should read them as a dict.

Comment: Add a `[` at the beggining of your text file and a `]` at the end.

Comment: You are missing the starting and ending `[ ]` and also the commas between the dicts: `{ .. } { ... }` should be `{ ... }, { ... }`. I don't know how it is to fix.